# VHDL: why is NOT 'Z' = 'X'

Tags: signals, vhdl, logical-operators

In VHDL, why is:

```
NOT 'Z' = 'X'
```

where Z is high impedence and X is unknown (see std_logic signal types below).

Context: This is only applicable to VHDL. I was given an exam question where a 'Z' signal was sent through an inverter and this yielded 'X'. I do not understand why this occurs and why the answer is simply not 'Z'.

```
'U': uninitialized. (signal hasn't been set yet)
'X': unknown (impossible to determine this value/result)
'0': logic 0
'1': logic 1
'Z': High Impedance (signal source when that source makes no effective contribution to the resolved value of the signal)
'W': Weak unknown signal (can't tell if it should be 0 or 1)
'L': Weak signal that should probably go to 0
'H': Weak signal that should probably go to 1
'-': Don't care
```

Comment: Okay, how about making your question less unclear.  `NOT 'Z' = 'X`` is an expression returning the BOOLEAN value TRUE.  What are you asking? Why is it TRUE? Because the enumeration literals are not the same. (5.2.2.1 *Each enumeration literal yields a different enumeration value.*, 9.2.3 Relational operators *The equality operator returns the value TRUE if the two operands are equal and returns the value FALSE otherwise.*). Add some context for those who could answer.

Comment: You don't seem to understand. This is only applicable to VHDL. I was given an exam question where a 'Z' signal was sent to an inverter and yielded 'X' which I do not understand why. I have added this clarification in my question - thanks for your advice.

Comment: You're right I didn't understand, your question is unclear. If you add the context from your last comment to the question, and look in the not_table in the aforementioned std_logic_1164-body.vhdl file you'll see that the not of 'Z' is indeed 'X'.  Notice that only '0', '1', 'L' and 'H' which represent binary values do not map to 'X' when inverted. What is the unary logical operator not of *no effective contribution* or *forcing* or *weak* metalogical values? You can assume the output of an inverter is forced, 'X' *for which the model is not able to distinguish between logic levels* (16.8.2.2).

Comment: It seems pretty clear to me.Four of the people who considered it not clear appear to have no clue about VHDL, so it's hardly surprising they find the question unclear.

Comment: And frankly, I think it's a good question. You should try to get it put not on hold. Good luck with that.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. Just because people don't know the answer doesn't mean it should be put on hold especially when I have not been told what to do to get it off hold!

Answer (score 3):

(I would have made this a comment but I can't) In the context of what you have said, if the input to an inverter (or any component for that matter) is 'Z' (driving high impedence), what would you expect the output to be? The result must fall within the set of defined values for a std_logic signal.

If no value is being driven on the input to the inverter (ie. there is only one signal driving the input, and it is 'Z'), the simulator will not be able to resolve the input value, which results in an unknown output ('X').

**EDIT**:

As user1155120 pointed out in the documents linked, the behaviour occurs due to the declared "not_table" in std_logic_1164-body, which states the following mapping:

```
-- truth table for "not" function
  constant not_table : stdlogic_1d :=
    --  -------------------------------------------------
    --  |   U    X    0    1    Z    W    L    H    -   |
    --  -------------------------------------------------
          ('U', 'X', '1', '0', 'X', 'X', '1', '0', 'X');
```

Comment: Resolution works for one driver (IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.7.2), the resolution table for std_logic will return the single value (see std_logic_1164-body.vhdl as above, function resolved - assuming we're talking std_logic, and the context for that has not been provided in the question). What's at issue in the "not" [std_logic return std_logic] function declaration and the not_table. You can assume the output of an inverter is forced, 'X' *for which the model is not able to distinguish between logic levels* (16.8.2.2).

Comment: I would expect the output to remain high impedence 'Z'... If you can explain why it is not 'Z' than my question is fully answered. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I read your comment after I posted; I'm just reading through the documents you linked now.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that a plain inverter (real hardware, not just VHDL now) is not a tri-state device. It is always driving, so if your input is floating, the inverter might see that as a logic `0` or a logic `1` somewhat at random and drive a solid `1` or `0` respectively, but there is no simple way to know which. In VHDL, when a signal is driven but we cannot determine if it is driven to `'0'` or `'1'`, we represent that with `'X'`.